# I am getting error object cannot be nill. when I parse it using loop it crashed and send out and my code is

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *animateImage =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= listImages.count ; i++)
{
    [animateImage addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[listImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

UIImageView *animation= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,110, 315,180)];

animation.animationImages=animateImage;

animation.animationDuration = 3.00;

[self.view addSubview:animation];
[animation startAnimating];
```

please help me. I dont know where i am doing wrong

Comment: For starts for should look like this
for ( int i = 0 ; i < listImages.count ; i++)

Comment: Also, log out your images before setting them; obviously, one of them does not get created (probably the file doesn't exist). `UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed...]; NSLog(@"%@", myImage); [animateImage addObject:myImage];`

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir Even better it should be `for (NSString *imageName in listImages) {` Fast Enumeration FTW.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you pasted and explained I can only guess but most probably you are loading an imageNamed: which doesn't exist - which leads to:

```
addObject:nil
```

You can check if image is nil and print it out to find out which one is causing a crash.

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= listImages.count ; i++)
{
    NSString* imageName = [listImages objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if(image)
    {
         [animateImage addObject:image]];
    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"non existing image: %@", imageName);
    }
}
```

Print all values from array and make sure you have all images listed there included in your target. Remember is case sensitive.

Also you should fix your loop:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < listImages.count ; i++)
{

}
```

Otherwise it will crash on last element since it's out of an array range.

Comment: +1 for this valid answer.sorry i didn't see before my answer.

Comment: Yeah it's crashing earlier than iteration loop with "nil" exception :) So it must be non existing image, but just after that it will crash on loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
NSMutableArray *animateImage =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= listImages.count ; i++)
{
    [animateImage addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[listImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

replace it like:

```
NSMutableArray *animateImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < listImages.count; i++) {
    [animateImage addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[listImages objectAtIndex:i]]];

}
```

Happy coding...:)

Answer (score 0):

You should do validation that your image is not nil before you add it to the array. Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *animateImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < listImages.count; i++) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[listImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (img != nil)
        [animateImage addObject:img];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what happened if you try add UIImage and image is nil you have error that 'object cannot be nil' but if you do if (image != nil) it won't happened. The if condition will prevent this crash from happen.